# Is it possible to locate wifi routers not in your range?

Tags: wifi

For example, would it be possible for someone to sit at home, and still see broadcasting networks within a radius of lets say, 50-100miles.

Comment: I have a feeling noise would be a problem. You would at least require highly specialized hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Typically WiFi networks have limited range which depends on transmission power,  antenna and frequency and is also limited by physical obstructions as well. A traditional wifi band of 2.4Ghz can reach up to 46m indoors and and 92m outdoors and is more prone to interference due to lack of wifi channels.

Whereas 5ghz frequency is less prone to interference, and if the 5ghz device is operating at the same power output of the 2.4ghz, the theoretical range if less than that of the 2.4GHZ network. 5Ghz is less able to penetrate walls and physical objects.

So unless you have a directional antenna that's capable of reaching that kind of distance, paired with the right frequency and matching the transmission power you might be able to access wireless signals from 50 - 100 miles away.

Comment: paired with...?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.

Using numbers from [here](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsp/article.php/3747656/WiFi-Define-Minimum-SNR-Values-for-Signal-Coverage.htm) and numbers from Scott's answers, let's say you can get a `1-bar` signal at `92 m`. If it's below `1-bar`, you can't see it. (Technically this isn't true, but it's true-enough for the scales of numbers we're talking here).

This means that you can see things within `92 m`, or `0.05717 miles`.

Let's extend this to `1 mile`. To make something `1 mile` away appear as though it's `92 m` away (i.e. to get a `1-bar` signal at `1 mile`), you would need `12dB` of gain. [Here](http://www.flyteccomputers.com/details.cfm?wid=3964&wb=HG2415EG-NM&wre=1&gclid=CJj8r_WYy8kCFUOBfgodhO0JGw) is a $50 antenna which has `15 dBi` of gain. *(One thing to mention: this antenna's gain is with respect to isotropic, but the range of WiFi usually assumes 3dB above isotropic, so this antenna does almost exactly what you would need)*

However, you want `50 miles`. This takes `29 dB` of gain to get a `1-bar` signal. [Here](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/13534013669100345041?q=high%20gain%20wifi%202.4%20GHz%20antenna&client=safari&rls=en&biw=1227&bih=1512&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.109332125,d.amc&tch=1&ech=1&psi=YD1mVpaXGeycjgSX-K-oCQ.1449541202130.7&prds=paur:ClkAsKraX0GL7Qtn78AazXOAct58tOkK3z8besTVBE33DXADRIkHrDPXa1WsVEDJve62Ccil3cEqjRAF1vobVehm4atERUhJOeUr1tPT69IC631minMG0iuniBIZAFPVH70-IJ0_BJMvXe03uFG1__0B1ENcBQ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL2tXrmcvJAhVptoMKHfvHB04Q8wIIpgYwBA) is a $50 antenna which claims `24 dBi` of gain, which doesn't quite cut it. [Here](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/4025276863346764495?q=high%20gain%20wifi%202.4%20GHz%20antenna&client=safari&rls=en&biw=1227&bih=1512&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.109332125,d.amc&tch=1&ech=1&psi=YD1mVpaXGeycjgSX-K-oCQ.1449541202130.7&prds=paur:ClkAsKraX-CUF7kFaaHLIi8E8A7fOYVz5-B6ajbuSJ30Cfp32DyJ_xec2CGifmgxwmwwXcQbTRJ0fB6g3XiFuftang-0tyCcbg2i7db_AZI-l4EM5BykutE4NRIZAFPVH72TJRBx6BFwf0CxcR4Enu97wuRJsA&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL2tXrmcvJAhVptoMKHfvHB04Q8wIIkwYwAg) is a $260 antenna which claims `27 dBi` of gain, which still isn't good enough. I'm having troubles finding antennae with much higher gain.

You'll need yet another `3 dB` of gain to get to `100 miles`, totaling `32.4 dB` to get a `1-bar` signal.

Another thing to note is that these numbers are in ideal conditions outdoors. Real life is not an ideal condition.

Your first problem doing what you want to do is simply getting an antenna with enough gain.

Then you have to deal with the problem of having a limited number of channels. Due to geometry, the geometric area in which you can get at least a `1-bar` signal is largest if you have no gain (because it is a circle). As you start getting gain, you start elongating and directing your beam, which decreases the geographic area which will get you a `1-bar` signal. This seems all fine and dandy because, typically, at your house, you don't have enough WiFi networks within range to cause them to start talking over each other so you can see and even connect to all the networks.

However, when you start pointing your antenna around the city, you will at some point direct your beam through an apartment complex or something, at which point you'll almost definitely have a very large number of access points on the same channel, effectively preventing you from getting any usable reading in that direction.